# Matlab: accessing a matrix like a database

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a matrix that is structured as a database as such:

```
M = [ 2010 5 ; 2010 7 ; 2011 8 ; 2012 20 ];
```

How can I retrieve all years 2010 or 2011?

I know I could do:

```
[ M(M(:,1)==2010,2) ; M(M(:,1)==2011,2) ]
```

But how can I generalize this for any number of years?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact answer to your question is to use `ismember`:

```
octave> years = [2010 2011];
octave> ismember (M(:,1), years)
ans =

   1
   1
   1
   0

octave> M(ismember (M(:,1), years), 2)
ans =

   5
   7
   8
```

However, depending what you gonna be doing with the data, it may be better to rearrange it in some other way. For example, maybe a cell array, one cell for each year holding an array with the values.

```
octave> M([2010 2011 2012]) = {[5 7] [8] [20]};
octave> M{2010}
  ans =

     5   7
```

Or if you gonna have more numbers for each entry, maybe a struct array with each struct having multiple fields, one of them the year. I have written before a [recipe](http://wiki.octave.org/Cookbook#Retrieve_a_field_value_from_all_entries_in_a_struct_array) to deal with such data before.

But really, if your data gets complicated and you think need a database, then this is probably not the right language to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
% Specify the years you're interested in
myyears = [2010, 2011];
% Get the row indices of those years
rowidx = ismember(M(:,1), myyears);
% Display the values (column 2) for those rows
M(rowidx, 2)
```